# Cuándo se libera un puntero C devuelto por una función del sistema

Tags: c, linux, api, unix

Estoy realizando pequeñas pruebas de llamadas a la API del sistema en Linux y tengo la siguiente duda.

Estoy llamando a la función ctime(). Según el manual de ctime, esta función devuelve un puntero a char.

El código compila y funciona y es este:

```
time_t seg = time(NULL);

char* cad = ctime(&seg);

printf("Fecha: %s\n", cad);
```

Mi duda es si tengo que llamar a free() con el puntero devuelto por ctime. Lo he intentado y me da un error en ejecución de puntero inválido. Mi pregunta es:
¿Quién se encarga realmente de liberar la memoria apuntada por ese puntero? He intentado buscar por internet pero no me ha quedado muy claro. Gracias.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

De la página del manual de `ctime`:

> The return value points to a statically allocated string which might be overwritten by subsequent calls to any of the date and time functions.

Es decir, **no tienes que liberarla**. El puntero devuelto *apunta* a un *buffer* interno del sistema, y **será sobreescrito por llamadas posteriores a la misma** `ctime( )`.

Si quieres conservar ese valor, tendrás que copiarlo a tu propio *buffer*, usando, por ejemplo:

```
char *ret = ctime( ... );
char *myBuff = (char *)malloc( strlen( ret ) + 1 );

*myBuff = 0;
strcat( myBuff, ret );
```

Este tipo de funciones **pueden dar problemas si son usadas desde múltiples hilos**, y suelen tener sus equivalente, con soporte multihilo. En el caso de `ctime( )`, su equivalente es `ctime_r( )`.

En cuanto a quién libera esa memoria, la respuesta es simple: **nadie**; una *hipotética* implementación de `ctime( )` sería algo así:

```
char *ctime( const time_t *timep ) {
  static char CTimeBuffer[1024]; // Tamaño máximo necesario.

  *CTimeBuffer = 0; // Limpiamos el buffer.

  ...
  ... // Código real de la función.
  ...

  return CTimeBuffer; // Devolvemos un puntero al buffer;
}
```

Como se ve, `CTimeBuffer` está declarada como `static`, lo cual hace que esté disponible durante toda la vida del programa, no siendo necesario reservar memoria, ni **tampoco liberarla**. Se liberará, junto al resto de recursos utilizados, cuando finalice el programa.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora ya lo entiendo.

Comment: @ycesar si esta respuesta ayudó a solucionar el problema de tu pregunta, por favor considera **[aceptarla](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-posts)** haciendo click en el **✔️**, que está bajo las flechas de votación, a la izquierda de la respuesta  (no se te descuenta nada por eso -todo lo contrario, ambos se [benefician](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)).

Answer (score 2):

No te hace falta.

Según la documentación (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/ctime/), el puntero devuelto por ctime apunta a un array propio de la librería, por lo que no te hace falta liberarlo. Lo que no te garantizan es que el resultado se mantenga si llamas a otras funciones de la librería. En otras funciones la situación puede ser diferente, por lo que siempre viene bien consultar la documentación.